# Telling injected automapper to use specific mapping profile in map function

Tags: c#, automapper

In some cases  one of my application services has to generate DTOs with anonymized data for the frontend. The idea was to use different AutoMapper profiles to either map the domain object to the DTO with all properties mapped or the anonymized DTO.
I generated these two profiles and injected them into the service. The AutoMapper is also injected into the service as `IMapper` and contains all mapping profiles of the application.

What I need now is to tell the mapper to use one specific profile in a call of the Map-function.
Something like this:

```
var anonymizedDto = _autoMapper.Map<SourceType, DestinationType> 
    (sourceObject, ops => ops.UseMappingProfile(_anonymizedMapingProfile));

var normalDto = _autoMapper.Map<SourceType, DestinationType>
    (sourceObject, ops => ops.UseMappingProfile(_normalMappingProfile));
```

Is this possible and if yes: how?

Comment: Injecting AutoMapper as a dependency is a bad idea in my experience. IN this case in particular, it would make it hard to tell what's going on, i.e. what sort of DTO will be created at runtime. I would suggest `new`ing up the mapper in the service with the desired configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, you can not change the profile when you call `Map`.

What you can do is inject two mappers that have been configured with different profiles.

```
public class MyService : IService {

   private readonly IMappingEngine _defaultMapper;
   private readonly IMappingEngine _anonymousMapper;

   public MyService(IMappingEngine defaultMapper, IMappingEngine anonymousMapper) {
       _defaultMapper = defaultMapper;
       _anonymousMapper = anonymousMapper;
   }

   public MyDto GetDefault() {
       return _defaultMapper.Map<MyDto>(sourceObject);
   }

   public MyDto GetAnonymous() {
       return _anonymousMapper.Map<MyDto>(sourceObject);
   }
}
```

In your dependency container, set up the constructor injection to respect the name of the ctor parameter. For example with [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/):

```
public void ConfigureAutoMappers(ConfigurationExpression x) {

    // register default mapper (static mapping configuration)
    Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(t => container.GetInstance(t));
    Mapper.Configuration.AddProfile<DefaultProfile>();
    var defaultAutomapper = Mapper.Engine
    x.For<IMappingEngine>().Use(() => defaultAutoMapper).Named("DefaultAutoMapper");

    // register anonymous mapper
    var anonConfig = new AnonConfigurationStore( // class derived from ConfigurationStore
        new TypeMapFactory(), 
        AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry.AllMappers()
    ); 
    anonConfig.ConstructServicesUsing(container.GetInstance);
    var anonAutoMapper = new MappingEngine(anonConfig);
    x.For<IMappingEngine>().Add(anonAutoMapper).Named("AnonAutoMapper");

    // Inject the two different mappers into our service
    x.For<IService>().Use<MyService>()
        .Ctor<IMappingEngine>("defaultMapper").Named("DefaultAutoMapper")
        .Ctor<IMappingEngine>("anonymousMapper").Named("AnonAutoMapper");
}
```